What is the purpose of this capacitor and what could its value be?
I am getting a short with this capacitor (C40) besides the 9977GM MOSFET when test it with a multimeter on diode mode.
I am not quite sure what is the purpose of this MOSFET. From what I saw online, it seems like it’s a decoupling capacitor to ensure low power supply impedence.
In that is right what could this value be? Would any capacitor work?



I found some schematic of its previous model that looks relatively similar.



What pupose it serves and what value it could be depends on how it connects to the N-FET. The other capacitor terminal is on Drain but the other goes down to another layer of PCB. Normally FETs don't require bypass caps so this whole thing depends on a larger circuit outside the photo.

”some issue with this capacitor” Please specify what issue.

Sorry that I did not explain clearly what’s the issue. This board is a g29 driving wheel motherboard where its motor no longer spins. When I measure the capacitor using a multimeter it appears to be shorted.

@user370625 So it drives some motors out of those J8 and J9 connectors? Did you take off the capacitor before measuring it being shorted, or did you measure the short while capacitor was in-circuit?

@Justme when I measured the capacitor in the circuit it was shorted. So I removed it from the circuit and no short anymore.

@user370625 You measured the whole circuit, not the capacitor. May I ask how you measured the short? Multimeter is ohm mode, multimeter it continuity mode, diode test mode, or some other mode?

Could you add a citation for where you found the schematic, what it is of, etc.?

@Justme The multimeter was In continuity mode. After removing the capacitor the pads that the capacitors were on were shorted. Could it be the mosfet that led to the short?
Also out of curiosity if I use a capacitor that did not have the same nanofarad, how big of an impact would it cause?

@TimWilliams sure! will provide a citation.

@user370625 So what did the multimeter indicated that you understood that there is a short? A simple beep? Some voltage reading of 0V? Some resistance reading of 0 ohms?

@Justme when I measured the pads there was a beep, I did not measure its resistance. I will try to measure and see if there is any resistance.

@user370625 The beep does not indicate a short. You need to read your multimeter manual under which conditions it beeps and when it does not when it is continuity test mode.

@Justme alright! will check and revert. Just to clarify, if I use a capacitor that did not have the same nanofarad, how big of an impact would it cause?

@user370625 Just put the cap back. You determined it is not shorted. If it were the load it driver would be constantly running. The circuit should work almost fine without it too, as it's not the only capacitor. You are still measuring things in-circuit and in beep mode, and interpreting the beep to indicate a short which it doesn't. Also the schematics are totally incomplete as it is missing the diodes that clearly are on the FET outputs.

@Justme thanks you for clarifying my doubts. I will do further testing to identify the component causing the issue. I will also remove the schematic to prevent any confusion.

@user370625 Please note your question about function and value of the capacitor are now answered, and this is diverging to a discussion about how to troubleshoot a circuit. If you find some answer good enough then accept it and ask new questions about some other subject. No do not remove the schematic, it was crucial info to answer what the capacitor does in the circuit.

@Justme silly me, I accidentally damaged the capacitor when putting it back to the circuit as it broke into half.
As you mentioned, I can leave the capacitor unsoldered the circuit should still function even without it. Or would It be better if i included a capacitor that is in the order of nanofarad?

I see you edited the images, but I don't see any text indicating where they came from, or what they are? Citation and attribution are required here to address plagiarism and copyright concerns.

Based on the schematics you found, the capacitor is used as an EMI filter to a load, such as a motor, which limits the slew rate and radiated emissions.
But C40 is not the problem, you measured it in circuit and you can't measure anything in-circuit. You measured the whole circuit that connects to the capacitor terminals.
So, C40 is likely fine. It might have a value in the order of nanofarads.
Also the initial assumption that there is a short when measuring the capacitor in-circuit is wrong. Multimeters in continuity test mode simply beep if the measured resistance or voltage drop crosses some threshold or not. If it beeps, it does not mean a short. It simply means what the manual says it means. There just is something that conducts enough for the meter to beep. There might be a diode or some resistance in the circuit or any path that conducts.
If the device does not work, the problem is elsewhere.

The capacitor may be shorted: they do sometimes fail that way. The FET is a more likely candidate, though.

@JohnDoty The capacitor was already re-tested out of circuit to be not shorted. The short was determined in-circuit. If the FET was shorted the motor would be constantly on. Multimeters in beep mode can't be used to determine if there really is a short circuit or not.
